# How to return value of identity after insert statement

Tags: .net, sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a problem to return value of identity after insert statement.

I must return this value by ExecuteScalar of OracleCommand. I'm using this query:

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
    returnId INT;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table (
        Text
    ) VALUES (
        :Text
    ) RETURNING Id INTO returnId;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(returnId);
END;
```

The result:

```
anonymous block completed
47
```

I believe that the value should be returned in a column so I can get him with the "ExecuteScalar" of OracleCommand.

How to return only "47" in column format?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
    returnId INT;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table (
        Text
    ) VALUES (
        :Text
    ) RETURNING Id INTO returnId;

    SELECT returnId INTO ReturnId FROM DUAL;
END;
```

Comment: Hi, I'm received the following error: "PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement"

Comment: Try it now. This will return a column named ReturnId. You can rename it to whatever.

Comment: I'm using inside "begin/end" block.

Comment: Now only is returning: "anonymous block completed". =[

Comment: Oops. Missing semi colon

Comment: Now is needing the variable :ReturnId

Comment: In .Net when I call the ExecuteScalar Command, I receive the following exception: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: var dbCommand = new OracleCommand(sql, (OracleConnection)connection);
object result = dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();

Comment: Why "(OracleConnection)connection"?

Comment: I create the connection like this: "var conn = OracleConnection(connectionString);", but the method receive the connection like "DbConnection connection", for this i need the typecast.

Comment: Have you debugged this and made sure that the connection is working correctly?

Comment: Oh now I remember. Use ExecuteOracleScalar *not* ExecuteScalar. It's been a long time since i've worked with Oracle